# Syntax for inserting values into db using var query

Tags: asp.net, database, var

I am using a var query to select values from the database such as:

```
var query = from meet in db.Meets
            where meet.Summary == meetName
            select meet.Meeting_ID;
```

Now my requirement is to insert few values in a database table. I have a table named "Meet_Emp" with 4 columns meetid(int), empid(int), empname(varchar), summary(varchar). I have all the data in string and int variables i.e. MeetingID, EmpID, EmpName, Title which I need to store in this table using var query.

How can I do it?

```
FinalProj2.Models.Meet_Emp newEmp = new FinalProj2.Models.Meet_Emp()
            {
                Employee_ID = empId;
                Meeting_ID = meetId;
                Employee_Name = empName;
                Summary = meetName;

            }
```

Comment: A 'var query' ?  Var is a keyword, which is a shorthand to indicate that you're declaring a variable, which is initialized with a certain type.  The query you're referring to is probably a LINQ to SQL query.

Comment: Yeah I know... but the syntax is bit different than the SQL query so wanted to know how to use the syntax here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are using LINQ to Entitites or LINQ to SQL.

Tejs is correct with LINQ to Entities.  If you are using LINQ to SQL, see this blog post:
[ScottGu's Blog: LINQ to SQL (Part 4 - Updating our Database)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx)

If you are using an EDMX file, you should reference namespace of the EDMX at the top of your code-behind/class/controller.  Usually that is your application name and the folder it is in:

```
using [ApplicationName].[FolderOfEDMXFile];
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this out, but I am getting "type or namespace Meet_Emp name could not be found" whenever I create an object for the table i.e. while Meet_Emp newEmp = new Meet_Emp();

Comment: The only thing I can think is that you need to reference the namespace of your model at the top of the code-behind/model/controller/class you are creating.  Usually that is "using [ApplicationName].[FolderOfEDMXFile];"  Are we getting closer?

Comment: Hey, I am able to make the object for the Table now... but getting error during assigning the values to its columns. Adding the code above.

Comment: I am getting errors on Employee_ID, Meeting_ID, Employee_Name and Summary... Error is : "Name Meeting_ID does not exists in current context"

Comment: I mean I also tried  FinalProj2.Models.Meet_Emp newEmp = new FinalProj2.Models.Meet_Emp()
            {
                newEmp.Employee_ID = empId;
                newEmp.Meeting_ID = meetId;
                newEmp.Employee_Name = empName;
                newEmp.Summary = meetName;

            }  which gives me an error only at newEmp.Employee_ID = empId stating that "Invalid initializer member declarator"

Comment: Can you open the EDMX file and see what the model namespace is under properties?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework, you simply do something like this:

```
Meet_Emp newEmp = new Meet_Emp
{
    meetid = MeetingID,
    empid = EmpID,
    empname = EmpName,
    summary = Title
};

db.Meet_Emps.Add(newEmp);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: no am not using entity framework. I am working directly through asp.net

Comment: Linq to sql syntax is pretty similar to this.

Comment: understood.. but somehow I am not able to make the object on the table i.e. in the code mentioned by Tejs, its Meet_Emp newEmp = new Meet_Emp... When I directly write Meet_Emp... I am getting error like "type or namespace Meet_Emp name could not be found"

Comment: That's code that is generated from the Entity Framework EDMX, or a class you defined with Code First. If you're not using Entity Framework, then this answer isn't very useful unfortunately.